# Find unbiased estimators for $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$.

Tags: self-study, spatial, unbiased-estimator, estimators, poisson-process

For the spatial homogeneous Poisson process, find unbiased estimators for $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$.

Attempt: Since the homogeneous Poisson process is over an area, how i would i go about constructing even an estimator for $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$? Would i assume that I have a $n$ sample data set and work from there? ie. $X_1,...,X_n$ and if so would i assume each sample has the same area?

Comment: If you integrate over the entire area (or simply ignore the spatial coordinates and only regard the time coordinate of the events) then you simplify a spatial into non-spatial Poisson process.

Comment: Regarding the $\lambda^2$ you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700670/unbiased-estimate-lambda2 which gives you an estimator $x$ with $E(x) = \lambda^2 + \lambda$, but you should be able to change that to an estimator $x^\prime = x+y$ (where you have to find this $y$) such that $E(x^\prime) = E(x) + E(y) =  \lambda^2$